# Growth Rate of Endpoint Versus Integral for an Exponential-Like Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function such that $\epsilon < f(x) < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ for all $x$, for some $\epsilon>0$. Define
  \begin{align*}
    M(x) & = \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt\right), \qquad \text{and} \\
    \Gamma(x) & = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{M(t)}dt.
  \end{align*}
I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that $\liminf_{x} M(x)\Gamma(x) < \infty$. It's easy to calculate this when $f$ is constant (so $M$ is an exponential function), but I'm having trouble proving (or disproving) it when $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: Can't you bound $M$ and $\Gamma$ by using your assumption on $f$?

Comment: @Siminore In that case you'd find that $M$ is decreasing at least exponentially with rate $\epsilon$, while $\Gamma$ is increasing at most exponentially with rate $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$; the product still tends to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is nice enough (e.g. continuous) for $M$ and $\Gamma$ to be differentiable, we have
$$(M\Gamma)'(x) = M(x)\Gamma'(x) + M'(x)\Gamma(x) = 1-f(x)M(x)\Gamma(x)$$
Since $M(0)\Gamma(0)=0$ and $M\Gamma$ is assumed to be continuous, we know that $M\Gamma$ is bounded from above by $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, since if $M\Gamma(x)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then $(M\Gamma)'(x) < 1-(\epsilon)\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right) =  0$, implying the existence of a maximum at some $x_0$ where $M\Gamma(x_0)>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, but $(M\Gamma)'(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! In fact no additional regularity needs to be assumed on $f$ for $M$ and $\Gamma$ to be differentiable; $f \in L^{1}_{loc}$ is sufficient for that.